# Lazy loading text in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, lazy-loading

I have an app that displays text to the user, but it takes each word and dynamically styles it, makes it pressable, and several things like that that take a long time to load. So when the user clicks to go to the next page (with ~400 words of text) the app freezes for a few seconds before it finally loads. Obviously, this is really annoying for the user.

So what I want to do is display the unstyled text while the dynamic text is loaded in the background (without freezing the app).

I assumed Suspense and lazy from React would be a good way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work. Admittedly I have no experience with either.

What I have tried is something like this:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const str =
  'pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar';
const arr = str.split(' ');

const RenderText = lazy(() => {
  arr.map((word) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.styledWord} onPress={() => null}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{word}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Text>{str}</Text>}>
          <RenderText />
        </Suspense>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  styledWord: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
});
```

Is there a good way to do this or something similar to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe you can try to render the text in a flatlist since the content is rendered asynchronously offscreen before coming to display.

Comment: @caslawter Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me like the performance gains from using a FlatList only come when there are enough items that you need to scroll down to see them. 

What I am trying to render will be shown on the screen at once . . . If there is some way to configure the FlatList to load everything bit by bit even though it is all in view of the user, that might work.